# Spring boot 3 and JMS configuration for Amazon SQS

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-sqs, java-17

The latest spring boot (i.e. 3.0.1) uses Spring JMS 6.0.3. And the latest Spring JMS that comes with the latest spring boot for `ConnectionFactory` uses `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory`, while the older JMS was using `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`. This was my bean setup and configuration before:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
class JmsConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var sqsClient: SqsClient

    @Bean
    fun sqsConnectionFactory(): SQSConnectionFactory =
        SQSConnectionFactory(ProviderConfiguration(), sqsClient)

    @Bean
    fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(): DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory {
        val factory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()
        factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory())
        factory.setDestinationResolver(DynamicDestinationResolver())
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun jmsTemplate(): JmsTemplate = JmsTemplate(sqsConnectionFactory())
}
```

However with the latest Spring boot, I cannot use `SQSConnectionFactory`, because it hasn't implemented its code based on `jakarta` rather `javax`.

Here are my SQS dependencies used:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

So now I cannot set the connection `factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory())`, because it complains `sqsConnectionFactory()` is not type of `jakarta` ConnectionFactory. Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't upgrade, or wait till amazon SDK supports the jakartaEE namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS has already published a dependency which supports Jakarta:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below connectionFactory -

```
private ConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory() {
        SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(awsRegion))
                .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();

        return new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), sqsClient);
}
```

Dependencies -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.78</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.